# ‘DelayedMatrixStats’ had non-zero exit status : Unable to install 'DelayedMatrixStats' (and failed to compile 'crayon' and 'HDF5Array')

Tags: r

```
Error: Unable to install 'DelayedMatrixStats' (and failed to compile 'crayon' and 'HDF5Array')

System: Windows 10 Pro, System type: 64-bit operating system, x64 based processor

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10), Rtools40 installed and placed into system path variables, Rstudio 1.4, Bioconductor Version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10)
```

To reproduce error:

```
      if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
         install.packages("BiocManager")
  

    BiocManager::install('DelayedMatrixStats')
```

**Output:**

```
Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Installing package(s) 'DelayedMatrixStats'


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
                   binary source needs_compilation

DelayedMatrixStats 1.12.1 1.12.3             FALSE


installing the source package ‘DelayedMatrixStats’


trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/bioc/src/contrib/DelayedMatrixStats_1.12.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 271827 bytes (265 KB)
downloaded 265 KB



The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\bullo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAr6ZPv\downloaded_packages’


Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, class, codetools, foreign, KernSmooth, Matrix, nlme, nnet, spatial

Old packages: 'crayon', 'HDF5Array'

Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
a


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:

**binary source needs_compilation**

**crayon     1.4.0  1.4.1             FALSE**

**HDF5Array 1.18.0 1.18.1              TRUE**



installing the source packages ‘crayon’, ‘HDF5Array’


trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/crayon_1.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 35769 bytes (34 KB)
downloaded 34 KB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/bioc/src/contrib/HDF5Array_1.18.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8071706 bytes (7.7 MB)
downloaded 7.7 MB


The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\bullo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAr6ZPv\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:


1: In install.packages(...) :   installation of package ‘DelayedMatrixStats’ had non-zero exit status 

2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :   installation of package ‘crayon’ had non-zero exit status 

3: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :   installation of package ‘HDF5Array’ had non-zero exit status
```

**Troubleshooting**

1. It seemed my `DelayedMatrixStats` was not installing because of crayon and HDF5Array if I chose to update/compile them (I attempted to rerun without updating, but it still did not work)
2. Next, I tried rerunning just the installation of crayon using -- `install.packages('crayon')` and I also tried rerunning `BiocManager::install("HDF5Array")` and the compilation failed again. (The old binary versions are fine, but I need the updated versions for DelayedMatrixStats)
3. I also made sure to unclick the "Use secure download method for HTTP", restarted R, and tried rerunning `install.packages('crayon')` #non-zero exit status
4. I changed my CRAN mirror  and still had a non-zero exit status with crayon
5. I then reinstalled R version 4 and Rstudio and Rtools40 (plus re-added to path)  #crayon still failed and had non-zero exit status
6. Uninstalled everything and deleted all connected files, then reinstalled R version 3.6.1, RStudio, and Rtools 3.5 (added to path) #crayon still failed and had non-zero exit status
7. Other things I've tried to install crayon which both gave me a non-zero exit status:

   ```
   install.packages('crayon', dependencies = TRUE)

   install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/crayon_1.4.1.tar.gz', repos = NULL)
   ```

DelayedMatrixStats, crayon, and HDF5Array have not been successfully installed, and continue to give me trouble.

Comment: `Installation path not writeable` is this your personal computer or do you have an admin who installs software for you?

Comment: This is a personal computer.

Comment: I started RStudio as administrator and re-ran BiocManager::install('DelayedMatrixStats'). I had a non-zero exit status for 'DelayedMatixStats', 'crayon', 'HDF5Array', 'Matrix', and 'nlme' this time.

Comment: check where your library is installed, using ```.libPaths()``` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/libPaths and see that you have permissions to write there

Comment: `"C:/Users/bullo/Documents/R/win-library/4.0" "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"` is the output given with `.libPaths()`. My default library which is the one stored in my personal user folder allows me Full control (Modify, Read and Execute, Read, Write).